# Highcharts Plotoptions Series

Tags: javascript, highcharts, series

I am currently using Highcharts in my website. In one of my charts (a Basic Column chart) I have multiple series, which I can click on the name displayed on the bottom to show/hide.

I can have a lot of series and I would like to limit the number of series to 3 at the same time. It means when it loads the graph, it shows only 3 series and the others are not shown. If I click on a 4th serie, one of the 3 originally present will disappear, so that the number of active serie always remain 3.

I've been looking for it and I found out I needed to do some modifications in the plotOptions.series field and I digged into the Highcharts API reference but didn't found what I wanted. My first attempt at the code would be something like this :

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    plotOptions:{
        series: {
            var series = this.series;
            var nb_of_visible_series = 0;              

            //Here i count the number of visible series
            for(var i=0; i<series.length; i++) {
              if(series[i].visible) {
                  nb_of_visible_series++:
              }
            }

            //If too many series are visible I'll randomly 
            //hide as many series as necessary
            if(nb_of_visible_series>3) {
                var nb_of_series_to_hide = nb_of_visible_series-3;
                while(nb_of_series_to_hide>0) {
                    var i=Math.floor(Math.random()*series.length);
                    if(series[i].visible) {
                        series[i].hide()
                        nb_of_series_to_hide--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is the idea but I don't know where to put it for real (not directly in the `plotOptions.series` field just like this I guess ?). I can put it in `plotOptions.series.events.legentItemClick` but then it will not be taken into account at the loading of the chart.

I'm looking for some tracks and advices about my code (I'm a JS beginner) and thank you in Advance. And sorry about my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure code you have written wouldn't work. Options for Highcharts should be javascript object, not some thing mixed between variables, options etc.

1) To get displayed on init only three series preprocess data, something like this:

```
var series = [{ data: [..], name: 'name 1' ..} , { data: [..], name: 'name 2' ..} , ... , {data: [..], name: 'name n'}];

for (var i = 0, len = series.length; i < len; i++) {
    series[i].visible = i < 3; //setup variable series.visible to show/hide on init load.
}

$('#container').highcharts({
    series: series //pass variable with updated visible option
});
```

2) As you noticed you need to write your own function for `legendItemClick` which will check how many series is visible (loop through `chart.series` and count `series.visible == true`). Then hide/show specific series using `series.hide() / series.show()`.

Comment: It's much better to handle event show of each series instead of legendItemClick because you can want to control visibility dynamically through show() and hide() methods and thus legendItemClick handler wouldn't be fired.

Comment: Question doesn't mention anything about using `hide()` and `show()` methods. Feel free to add your answer with support for `hide()` and `show()`.